# Why adding image as item in Layer-list of drawable file cause image not to scale/missing

Tags: android, drawable, layer-list

Missing image issue with Android layer-list drawable file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
      <size
        android:width="186dp"
        android:height="57dp" />
      <solid android:color="@color/gray_lightest" />
      <corners android:radius="8dp" />
    </shape>
  </item>
<item
    android:bottom="30dp"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_list_add"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:left="82dp"
    android:right="82dp"
    android:top="8dp" />
</layer-list>
```

Here @drawable/ic_list_add is SVG file. In some devices, Samsung s6 and Moto E. Image are missing. While it works on most of the devices. Also the problem comes only while using layout_weight in which case layout_width is set as 0dp within constraint layout.

Comment: What folder do you have the drawable in? Is this an incorrect density folder issue?

Comment: drawable is in res directory. As image ic_list_add is an SVG file, It is added in a drawable folder. I didn't get what is incorrect density folder issue here. As no png file is involved. I can make it work by removing image item from this XML file and adding it in AppcompatTextView view using the drawingTop attribute. My question, why it doesn't work with this approach with these two Model only Samsung S6 and Moto E. Otherwise most of the devices, it working perfectly fine.